# Flask - Setting cookies specific to a user on a voting app

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I have a voting app where a user can choose from a selection of polls and then vote on one of the two options in the poll they selected.  I do not want a user to be able to vote twice on the same poll.  How can I do that?  The following code will show what I have tried (pay attention to 'vote_stamp').

This is from my app.py:

```
@app.route('/vote/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def vote(id):
  if not g.user:
    return redirect('/login')

  has_voted = False
  total_votes = 0
  vote_stamp = request.cookies.get('vote_stamp')

  cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
  try:
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE (id='{id}');")
    question = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Choices WHERE (question_id='{id}');")
    choices = cursor.fetchall()
  except:
    return 'Error fetching data'

  if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
      selected_choice_id = request.form.get('selected_choice')
    except:
      return redirect(f'/vote/{id}')

    try:
      cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Choices SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE (id='{selected_choice_id}');")
      cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Choices WHERE (question_id='{id}');")
      choices = cursor.fetchall()
      mysql.connection.commit()
      cursor.close()
    except:
      'Error voting'

    has_voted = True
    for choice in choices:
      total_votes += choice[3]
  
  if vote_stamp:
    return 'Already voted'

  context = {
    'question': question,
    'choices': choices,
    'has_voted': has_voted,
    'total_votes': total_votes
  }

  response = make_response(render_template('vote.html', **context))

  if has_voted:
    vote_stamp = os.urandom(24)
    response.set_cookie('vote_stamp', vote_stamp)

  return response
```

This is vote.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block head %} 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/vote.css')}}">
  <script defer src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vote.js') }}"></script>
  <title>Voting On: {{question[1]}}</title>
{% endblock %} 
{% block content %} 
  <div><h1>{{question[1]}}</h1></div>
  <form class="vote-form" action="/vote/{{question[0]}}" method="POST">
    {% if has_voted %}
     {% for choice in choices %}
      <div>{{choice[1]}} {{choice[3]}} ({{choice[3]*100//total_votes}}%)</div>
     {% endfor %}
     <input id="btn-viewpolls" class="btn-submit" type="button" value="View Polls" onclick="window.location.href='/'">
    {% else %} 
      {% for choice in choices %}
        <div><input type="radio" name="selected_choice" value="{{choice[0]}}">{{choice[1]}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Vote">
    {% endif %}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to rethink your check if the user has already voted two times. The problem with a cookie is, that he can simply remove it and vote again. You are already using a user model, so why not simply add another column to the database with how many times the user already voted or even better make a seperate model with polls and store there the user id and counts. this way you can check each poll in your database instead of relying on something the user can easily manipulate.